# clamd on several ports with different databases

Tags: clamav

Is it possible to run a `clamd` on one machine with different ports and each of them hold another database?

> 3310 = official databases
> 3311 = unofficial databases
>
> 3312 = yara rules

p.s. CentOS 6/7

Comment: Yes. Simply create multiple configuration files, each with different port numbers (and any others settings that should not overlap ) and and use the -c option to start versions of clamd with different settings and run them concurrently. In theory at least. What have you tried though ?

Comment: In theory at least ;-) my hope was, that another one had already checked this out. well, thank you so far. i will configure it out and post my solution.